# The "focus" of a statute (RJR Nabisco v. European Community)

Tags: jurisdiction, statutes

In the US Supreme Court's decision in RJR Nabisco v. European Community, the court utilizes a two-step framework for analyzing matters of extraterritoriality. In the second step of this framework, the court states:

"If the conduct relevant to the statute’s focus occurred in the United States, then the case involves a permissible domestic application even if other conduct occurred abroad; but if the conduct relevant to the focus occurred in a foreign country, then the case involves an impermissible extraterritorial application regardless of any other conduct that occurred in U. S. territory".

See: https://www.supremecourt.gov/opinions/15pdf/15-138_5866.pdf

What exactly is meant by the "focus" of a statute?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As there is no any applicable special definition of "focus" in that context, the [plain meaning rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plain_meaning_rule) applies: the "focus" of a statute is what the statute is **focused on**.

Any ordinary synonyms apply: *concentrated on*, *revolves around*, *addresses itself to*.

What exactly a statute is focused on is determined by way of its interpretation and analysis. This is part of what judges do.